# Why doesn't objectAnimator doesn't call setter method

Tags: android, objectanimator

I am learning how to animate an object on android by using ObjectAnimator but I don't see it update my setter method. Suppose I have a custom view which draw a simple text on the display and there is private variable (curnum) that an objectAnimator will operate:

```
public class TempView extends View {

    private Float cur_num = new Float(0.0);
    private float curnum = 0f;

    public TempView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setCurnum()
    {
        curnum++;
        cur_num = new Float(curnum);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(8);
        paint.setTextSize(100);

        canvas.drawText(cur_num.toString(), 150, 150, paint);


    }
}
```

Now on my Activity class, I have an action bar item which start an animation:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.


    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.startanim) {

       TempView v = (TempView)findViewById(R.id.tempView);
       ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "curnum", 0f, 1f);
       anim.setDuration(1000L);
       anim.start();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But somehow if I put a breakpoint on the setter method, it is never hit.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: setCurnum() should be setCurnum(float value) ?

Comment: **invalidate()** inside the setter function is ABSOLUTELY NECESSARY for the animation to run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in the [developers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html):

> The object property that you are animating must have a setter function
>   (in camel case) in the form of set(). Because the
>   ObjectAnimator automatically updates the property during animation, it
>   must be able to access the property with this setter method.
>
> The getter (if needed) and setter methods of the property that you are
>   animating **must operate on the same type as the starting and ending
>   values that you specify** to ObjectAnimator.

For example, you must have `targetObject.setPropName(float)` and `targetObject.getPropName(float)` if you construct the following `ObjectAnimator`:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(targetObject, "propName", 1f)
```

So you need to change your method to:

```
setCurnum(float f)
```